# I can't make a table with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a problem with that code, for some reason It didn't work. but the two functions i did the almost the samething but in the second one the code didn't work and I don't know why.

here is following the code:

```
    import numpy
    import pandas
    import statsmodels.api as sm
    def simple_heuristic(file_path):
        id_pass = []
        name = []
        suviver = []
        df = pandas.read_csv(file_path)
        for passenger_index, passenger in df.iterrows():
            passenger_id = passenger['PassengerId']

            if passenger['Sex'] == 'male':
                id_pass.append(passenger_id)
                name.append(passenger['Name'])
                suviver.append(1)
            else:
                id_pass.append(passenger_id)
                name.append(passenger['Name'])
                suviver.append(0)

        predictions = {'id':pandas.Series(id_pass),
                        'Name': name,
                        'Suviver': pandas.Series(suviver)}

        return pandas.DataFrame(predictions)
    def complex_heuristic(file_path):
        id_pass = []
        name = []
        sex = []
        suviver =[]
        socileco = []
        df = pandas.read_csv(file_path)
        for passenger_index, passenger in df.iterrows():
            passenger_id = passenger['PassengerId']

            if passenger['Sex'] == 'female' or (passenger['Age'] < 18 and passenger['Pclass']==1) :
                id_pass.append(passenger_id)
                name.append(passenger['Name'])
                suviver.append(1)
            else:
                id_pass.append( passenger_id)
                #name.append(passenger['Name'])
                #sex.append(passenger['Sex'])
                suviver.append(0)
                #socileco.append(passenger['Pclass'])

        predictions = {'Idx' : pandas.Series(id_pass),
                        'Name': name,
                        'Sobreviveu': pandas.Series(suviver)},
        return pandas.DataFrame(predictions)
    print simple_heuristic('titanic-data.csv')
    print complex_heuristic('titanic-data.csv')
```

But always that I'm trying to run the code I get the same error

```
File "heuristic.py", line 161, in <module>
    print complex_heuristic('titanic-data.csv')
  File "heuristic.py", line 159, in complex_heuristic
    return pandas.DataFrame(predictions)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 422, in __init__
    raise ValueError('DataFrame constructor not properly called!')
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

I did the samething but in one of them the code worked but in the second one it didn't

Comment: Welcome to SO, good that you have shown your efforts. Kindly add samples of input and output too with code tags in your post and let us know then.

Comment: try `predictions = {'id':pandas.Series(id_pass),
                        'Name': pd.Series(name),
                        'Suviver': pandas.Series(suviver)}`

Comment: @pyd it worked but I don't know why can you explain to me?

Comment: can you print `id_pass,name,suviver` all three and see the object and its length

Answer (score 0):

first of all, you don't need to use pandas.series, you can just

```
 predictions = {'id':id_pass,
                    'Name': name,
                    'Suviver': suviver}
```

The pandas will understand that is a list and your data frame will work properly.